# Autos window doesn't show return value when expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, struct, visual-studio-debugging, value-type

Given the following lines of code:

```
using System;

struct MyIntPtr
{
    private unsafe void* m_value;
}

class Program
{
    static IntPtr   GetIntPtr()   { return new IntPtr();   }
    static MyIntPtr GetMyIntPtr() { return new MyIntPtr(); }

    static void Main()
    {
        var ptr1 = GetIntPtr();
        var ptr2 = GetMyIntPtr();
    }
}
```

I expected both method calls in Program.Main to show return values in the Autos window. For some reason that I can't quite understand, only the first line behaves that way:

(+
Program.GetIntPtr returned
0
System.IntPtr).

My understanding, according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx, is that function return values that return value types the size of pointers should indeed show the return values when called in the Autos window. What am I doing wrong?